# Setup a Fax server

Tags: fax

A client asked for a **web to fax** application written in php. But I have no idea how to do this.

I believe php or any other web application **can't** communicate with the modem **directly**. So there should be some sort of **service** or daemon handling the job and be the line between web interface and modem.

Tried googling things a bit and some words like `HylaFAX` and `AvantFax` came out. Still can't figure out.

I prefer writing the web interface myself to have custom language support and better user experience.

So in the end what I am asking is how to achieve a web to fax application from scratch. From setting up server and making the web application. Even some directions would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install HylaFAX and invoke the sendfax command-line options through PHP's exec or system calls.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer is flexible, [DeliveryWare](http://www.merkur.com/deliveryware.html) may be a good alternative.

Other than learning PHP, interfax looks pretty simple.

1. For testing, follow instructions [here](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/samples/php/fax-from-php-tutorial).
2. Once your testing complete, if you need to fax to more than one number, setup a pay account per [these](http://www.interfax.net/en/help/dev) instructions.
3. Also, if sensitive information (PII, CC #'s, etc) are being sent through this, be sure to use SSL.

**EDIT**
If you don't already have a server setup, you'll probably want to go with a LAMP stack.  An install of Ubuntu Server should do the trick.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP
- http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-11.10-lamp
- http://www.linuxcandy.com/2011/11/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-1110.html

Please be sure to let everyone know what solution you eventually choose.  With e-mail and the invention of the google machine, I imagine there's not such a need for fax anymore.

```
    /**************** Settings begin **************/

    $username = ''; // Enter your Interfax username here
    $password = ''; // Enter your Interfax password here
    $faxnumber = ''; // Enter your designated fax number here in the format +[country code][area code][fax number], for example: +12125554874
    $texttofax = 'My text goes here'; // Enter your fax contents here
    $filetype = 'TXT'; // If $texttofax is regular text, enter TXT here. If $texttofax is HTML enter HTML here

    /**************** Settings end ****************/

    $client = new SoapClient("http://ws.interfax.net/dfs.asmx?wsdl");

    $params->Username  = $username;
    $params->Password  = $password;
    $params->FaxNumber = $faxnumber;
    $params->Data      = $texttofax;
    $params->FileType  = $filetype;

    $faxResult = $client->SendCharFax($params);

    print_r($faxResult);
    ?>
```

Comment: There a few thing I need to clarify: 1. I know how to code php. 2. And I know to setup L.A.M.P 3. Using services like InterFax is not what I'm looking for. That's why I started this topic. I know php, I have server and I have the fax modem. But I don't know the tools for making the server. How should php access fax modem ? such direct access would be impossible. So there should be a package/service running on server. But what's that ?

Comment: You'll want to look into command line programs that can handle the faxing, since I highly doubt PHP can do it itself. Then use PHP's exec() or system() to run the program with the required parameters. Hopefully someone here has some command line fax experience.